# Position of global fiducials

Tags: board, fiducial

I have two question for placement of global fiducials on my board:

1. In the board below you see two fiducials and a component (SMD connector). I would like to place the connector on the very edge of the board but it would interfere with the fiducials. Is it possible to move the fiducials inwards?

[image: Board with fiducials and connector]

2. According to [this document](https://www.accutroninc.com/pdf/download/fiducial.pdf) for fiducial deisgn guidelines, the placement shall be "the sum of 7.62mm and the minimum fiducial clearence" away from the board edge. In my case, the fiducial is 1mm in diameter, with a 2.7mm cutout. Does that mean I have to place it 2.7mm/2 + 7.62mm = 8.97mm away from the board edge?? Is that not a little bit too much?

Comment: Fiducials are only there for the calibration of the PnP machine (unless you are also designing for flying lead). Most board houses have some guidelines about size, placement, quantity, and style that they want you to follow. These can change depending on how your board is panelized.

Comment: I would ask the house if these fiducials are really needed.The manufacturer I outsource the assembly of my PCB's, panelizes the PCB's I made and adds fiducials to the panel. I only add fiducials where location/orientation really matters (eg angle sensors using Hall effect)